# How to bring two outer columns close to the middle column

Tags: html, css

I want the first and last column to be closer to the middle column. This is what i have so far.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
}

.images {
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
}

.fault {
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="images">
    <ul>
      <li><img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/cat.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/cat.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/cat.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/cat.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/cat.png" /></li>
      <li><img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/cat.png" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

If anybody could help me out it would be great. I have this code so far and it kind of works but not 100%. the outer two are too far from the middle one.

Comment: could you also provide your current css? so we can also see your current result

Comment: @Spoochy I have done that.

Comment: What is in your class `images`?

Comment: is there a specific reason for you to use display grid?
otherwise i would suggest to use display flex instead

Answer (score 0):

Just change the value of `grid-column-gap` property of `ul` css styles.

```
grid-column-gap: 2px;
```

Answer (score -2):

Just align the images in the `li` based on their number in the grid row

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

li:nth-child(3n+ 1) {
  text-align: right;
}

li:nth-child(3n + 2) {
  text-align: center;
}

li:nth-child(3n + 3) {
  text-align-last: left;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="images">
    <ul>
      <li><img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/140/100" /></li>
      <li><img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/140/100" /></li>
      <li><img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/140/100" /></li>
      <li><img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/140/100" /></li>
      <li><img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/140/100" /></li>
      <li><img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/140/100" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```